# Split and then Joining the String step by step - C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my string:

`www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end`

I split it with `/` into a list of separated words:`myString.Split('/').ToList()`

Output:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
questions
ask
user
end
```

and I need to rejoin the string to get a list like this:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com/questions
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end
```

I think about linq aggregate but it seems it is not suitable here. I want to do this all through linq

Comment: Why don't you see `Aggregate` as suitable? I think it's pretty reasonable

Comment: @Freggar: `Aggregate` returns a *single* value, not `IEnumerable<T>`; it's possible to solve with `Aggregate`, but it's an *overshoot* in the context

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try iterating over it with foreach

```
var splitted = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end".Split('/').ToList();
string full = "";
foreach (var part in splitted)
{
    full=$"{full}/{part}"
    Console.Write(full);
}
```

Or use linq:

```
var splitted = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end".Split('/').ToList();
var list = splitted.Select((x, i) => string.Join("/", a.Take(i + 1)));
```

Comment: I need to use linq in this case, not using a foreach

Comment: @Nofuzy any reason why you *need* to use Linq?

Comment: @Nofuzy if you really have to, there's my updated answer. It's tricky

Comment: In fact the linq `.Select()` behind the scenes does pretty much the same as `foreach` both do iterate the IEnumerable. In this particular case, using `Linq` over `foreach` is imho, pretty much subjective.

Comment: the `foreach` version put a `/` in the beginning. It is a litle bit not the same as the version with LINQ.

Answer (score 7):

*Linq* with side effect:

```
  string prior = null;

  var result = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end"
    .Split('/')
    .Select(item => prior == null
       ? prior = item
       : prior += "/" + item)
    .ToList();
```

Let's print it out

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com/questions
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user
www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end
```

Comment: What do you mean by side effect?

Comment: @Nofuzy: changing `prior` variable while executing Linq query

Comment: So what is the problem with that?

Comment: @Nofuzy: side effects (mixing query and command in the extract) make the code at least *less readable* and often difficult to maintain and debug (the code does something which we don't expect).

Answer (score 4):

Linq without side effects ;)
`Enumerable.Aggregate` can be used here if we use `List<T>` as a result.

```
var raw = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end";

var actual = 
    raw.Split('/')
       .Aggregate(new List<string>(),
                 (list, word) =>
                 {
                     var combined = list.Any() ? $"{list.Last()}/{word}" : word;
                     list.Add(combined);
                     return list;
                 });
```

Comment: Nice, no side effects and `Aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

without Linq write below code,

```
var str = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/user/end";
        string[] full = str.Split('/');
        string Result = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < full.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(full[i]);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < full.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Result = full[i];
            }
            else
            {
                Result += "/" + full[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Result);
        }
```